# Reactive Form Exception for file input

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following reactive form with material inputs setup in HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input
    matInput
    accept=".txt"
    autocomplete="off"
    floatPlaceholder="always"
    formControlName="input"
    multiple="multiple"
    placeholder="Input"
    type="file"
    (change)="fileChanged($event)"
  />
</form>
```

And it is defined as such in typescript (Angular 9):

```js
private buildForm(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    input: [null, [Validators.required]],
  });
}
```

The workflow is that I have a wizard so that in step 1 it displays the form, in step 2 it parses the content that was passed in to records that are displayed into a grid, and in step 3 it submits the request to the back-end.

The issue that I'm running into is that going from step 1 to step 2 works fine, the text files get parsed properly and it is building the records in my grid. However, if I try to go from step 2 back to step 1 (lets say that the user wants to add a new file or remove an existing one) then I get the following exception in the console:

> ERROR DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not,
> or is no longer, usable

My guess is the value persisted in the `FormGroup` does not line up to what the HTML is expecting in the value and so it craps out.

Is there something that I can do so that the input can reference the files that the user previously selected?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you could save the uploaded object's url somewhere in service, session or local storage and then in ngOnInit make input reference reference it again ?

Comment: @ihorbond persisting it in localstorage didn't work for me. I was ultimately able to get buy-in from the client to just reset the form if the user goes back. But what was odd was that I got the same error if I tried: `this.form.get('input').reset()` but I didn't when I called `this.form.reset()`